# Python: intercative program like arm-tor

Tags: python, interactive

I'm writing a program in python and I'd like to add some feature that I find in arm-tor's program. In particular I'd like to use the "page" function that let me to switch from page 1 to another. What I think that I could try is to catch a pressed key and find a match with a "hotkey list" so do the corresponding function, but this doesn't work in "real time" like arm-tor do. What should I try out? Can someone suggest me something? I don't know where to start.

The situation in a server program should be like this:
-page 1 : log page (show when a client connect at what port etc..)
-page 2 : list of connected clients (ips, etc..)
-page 3 : CPU usage, disks status, etc...

Comment: What you could do is use msvcrt.getch() to get pages (1,2,3,4). You could then have different funcions or scripts that rendered each page. There are some videos [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDsmVH7eJCs) that explain how the connections work, but nothing as interactive as I explained. If you need more help, reply.

Comment: Thanks to the reply, that worked for me.. but I'm running Ubuntu so I've just installed getch and than used getch.getch()

Comment: For your user log, you can have a separate program. That connection finder that writes to a file and adds new connections. That way the main program only reads the file and doesn't have to load all of the connections each time.

Comment: Or more simply ed efficiently: a script that read&decode lines from `/proc/net/tcp` in a while loop for refreshing and a time-out for not over-use the CPU; and put this script in the main program and in the first lines `pid = subprocess.Popen(args=["gnome-terminal", "--command=python net.py"]).pid` where net.py is the sub-script